# Getting column text from webView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

How to get column text from webView. I separated the contents of the html page into columns with:

```
 public void injectJavascript() {
    String js = "javascript:function initialize() { " +
            "var d = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];" +
            "var ourH = window.innerHeight; " +
            "var ourW = window.innerWidth; " +
            "var fullH = d.offsetHeight; " +
            "var pageCount = Math.floor(fullH/ourH) + 1;" +
            "var currentPage = 0; " +
            "var newW = pageCount*ourW; " +
            "d.style.height = ourH+'px';" +
            "d.style.width = newW+'px';" +
            "d.style.webkitColumnGap = '2px'; " +
            "d.style.margin = 0;" +
            "d.style.webkitColumnCount = pageCount;" +
            "}";
    loadUrl(js);
    loadUrl("javascript:initialize()");
}
```

Now I want to get content of concret column (for example - 6). I try to invoke *onJsAlert()* method in WebChromeClient. What I must call in the next method for take text of 6 page?

```
  loadUrl("javascript:alert(????)");
```

Comment: Did you found any solution?